# Monkey patching ActiveRecord "where" method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm trying to add some additional functionality to `where` method in ActiveRecord. I reached half way by doing monkey patch but facing problem with chain queries.

Ex:

1. `User.where(id: 10, name: 'Blob')`

When I execute above code my new functionality is working as expected.
It triggers modified `where` method and gives query params as 
`query_params = { id: 10, name: 'Blob' }`

2. `User.where(id: 10).where(name: 'Blob')`

In this case i'm getting only 
`query_params = { id: 10 }`

I'm just printing the query params and delegating to super class:

```
def where(query, *values) 
  query.each do |key, value| 
    if value.is_a?(Array) and value.flatten != value 
      Rails.logger.debug "Where Clause Params" 
      Rails.logger.debug "#{query}" 
      Rails.logger.debug "#{caller.join("\n")}" 
      break 
    end  
  end 
  super 
end
```

This is how I extend modified `where` file into ApplicationRecord

```
 ApplicationRecord.extend CoreExtensions::ApplicationRecord::WhereLog
```

It would be great if anyone helps.

Comment: And how does your monkeypatch look like?

Comment: I'm just printing the query params and delegating to super class.


 `def where(query,*values)
  query.each do |key,value|
    if value.is_a?(Array) and value.flatten != value
      Rails.logger.debug "Where Clause Params"
     Rails.logger.debug "#{query}"
      Rails.logger.debug "#{caller.join("\n")}"
      break
    end
  end
  super
end`

Comment: Tried to reproduce, didn't have any problem.

Comment: Can you please try this  User.where.not(id:1)